# Como puedo encontrar el mayor valor de un array

Tags: python, array

tengo un script de python en el que hago una operación y al terminar me devuelve un array con 10.000 valores, necesito encontrar el mayor valor entre el primer dato y el dato 1000. Luego el mayor valor entre el dato 1000 y el 2000 y así sucesivamente. ¿Alguien sabe como podría hacer esto?

Pensé en hacer pequeños arrays de 1000 valores para buscar de uno en uno, pero no creo que sea la solución más optima.

Seria de gran ayuda si alguien pudiera orientarme.

Comment: ¿Los valores del Array son enteros?

Answer (score 0):

Como dices la solución pasaría por hacer listas más pequeñas basadas en el tamaño por el que quieres segmentar:

```
from random import random
import math

nums = [random() for _ in range(0, 10000)] # Esta debería ser tu lista, para simplificarlo genero una aleatoriamente
size = 1000 # El tamaño de las partes

chunk_numbers = math.ceil(len(nums) / size) # aquí obtienes el número de partes
chunks = [nums[_ * size:_ * size + size] for _ in range(0, chunk_numbers)] # generas las partes
maximos = [max(_) for _ in chunks] # recuperas el valor máximo
```

O haciéndolo del tirón:

```
import math

nums = [] # La lista en cuestión
size = 1000
maximos = [max(nums[_ * size:_ * size + size]) for _ in range(0, math.ceil(len(nums) / size))]
```